# Inapppurchase Receipt

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

I am developing the application with non renewable subscriptions, it is working fine with iOS6, now i changed the deployment target into 7. `TransactionReceipt` was deprecated in iOS6, so i move with `NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];`

```
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
```

But it returns the nil receipt. also the encode data also nil. Anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should get appStore receipt, when notification about purchased transaction is received, check [SKPaymentTransactionObserver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/SKPaymentTransactionObserver).

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions
```

Non-renewable subscriptions aren't persistent in receipt and removed after transaction finished.